# How to set Laravel to generate files with required permissions

Tags: php, laravel, jenkins, permissions, chmod

I have a deploy BASH script which runs as Jenkins CI job. It runs under the **jenkins user**. Deploy needs to delete old directory and replace it with new one. But there is a problem. Laravel generates the files like session or cache with **chmod 644 as www-data user**. It means although Jenkins is in the **www-data group** he can not delete the generated files cause group has only read permission.

I found something about permissions in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#local-files-and-visibility), but it does not work cause it is only for storage/app folder.

The question is is there a way to force Laravel or PHP demon to generate files with required permissions e.g. 664? Hope it is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64251935/487813) will work

Comment: I am not sure about it. It should be handled on www-data or Laravel level. This is not clear.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't try to modify the installer. Install the project files THEN change the permissions to match your use case.

Comment: The problem is not with permissions I set. The problem is with permissions which set up www-data for new files in the future. It set it up to 644 which means I as group member can not delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution is to set up ACL privileges for parent directory via setfacl command.

```
setfacl -R -dm "g:www-data:rw" /path/to/dir
```

This ensures the generated files will inherit the ACL privileges from parent dir.

Answer (score 0):

My straight forward solution is to run endless background script as root which find and deletes required directories every 10 seconds. It runs as nohup so it is still running although I close the terminal.

```
while true
do
  find /var/www -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'deploy-old-*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
  sleep 10
done
```